# Как добавить css файл к html странице в ASP.Net проекте?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Изучаю книгу по ASP.Net MVC 4. Проект создаваемый средой VS в книге немного отличается от моего так как устарел. По книжной инструкции я должен добавить таблицу стилей добавив строку:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Site.css" />
```

Но перепробовав все известные мне варианты таблица остается невидимой.

```html
@model WebApplication1.Models.FirstModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>RsvpForm</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=@Href("~/Content/Site.css") />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css") />
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary()

        <p>Your name: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) </p>
        <p>Your email: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)</p>
        <p>Your phone: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone)</p>
        <p>
            Will you attend?
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.WillAttend, new[] {
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Yes, I'll be there", Value = bool.TrueString},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "No, I can't come", Value = bool.FalseString}
            }, "Choose an option")
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit RSVP" />
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Так выглядит обозреватель:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так выглядит окно браузера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если в браузере открыть localhost:65516/Content/Site.css что получится?

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin Страница не найдена

Comment: Как вариант, если вы делаете в Visual Studio, можете из `Solution Explorer (Обозреватель решений)` перенести ваш файл мышкой через `drag'n'drop` на страницу, путь вроде как автоматически должен проставиться. Если путь будет такой же, то тогда надо будет подумать, если нет, то скорее всего заработает.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin Перетащил как сказали, но ничего не изменилось =(

Comment: Вы стили должны подключать на мастер странице, а не на каждой. В net. core стили хранятся в папке wwwroot. Меняйте книгу, у Вас скорей всего книга не подходит под net. core

Comment: проверьте что в бандлах у вас написано

Comment: Папка content есть (видится)? Только сss не видит? Возможно нужно Copy-Handler прописать для сss?

Comment: Я только начал изучение веб технологий. Я не понимаю, что значит "бандл" и "Copy-Handler". Но у меня действительно есть папка wwwroot с файлами типа css, html, js. Видимо мне нужно взаимодействовать с ней. Может @WebMorda Eikhner nick_n_a подскажите литературу которая мне поможет?

Comment: Можете посмотреть [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/)

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию статические файлы хранятся в папке wwwroot.

Если вы хотите указать свою папку, вы должны переопределить путь в файле Program.cs Для этого вам необходимо добавить `.UseWebRoot("Content")`.

Выглядит примерно так:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()          
            .UseWebRoot("Content")   
            .Build();
}
```

После этого вы можетк обращаться к статическим файлам, только теперь они будут браться из папки Content, а не из wwwroot.

Answer (score 0):

В файле Startup.cs нужно подключить статику:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

А, требуется ASP.NET MVC 4, не сразу заметил. Но скорее всего там так же.

Comment: В файле Startup уже существует метода Configure. Кроме метода "app.UseStaticFiles();" там вызывается: 
app.UseMvc(routes =>  {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
Без которого страница в браузере совсем не отображается.